# Gibt es etwa die Genitiv-Version von „trotz allem“ gar nicht?

Tags: preposition, dative, spelling, history, genitive

Nicht weil ich die unbedingt verwenden will, nur aus Neugier. Gibt es die Genitiv-Version von *trotz allem* nicht?

> trotz alles

wäre meine Vermutung, welche ich so gut wie nie gelesen habe.

Nichtsdestotrotz ist hier ein Ngram, welches vorschlägt, dass es die vorher gab und die nun praktisch ausstirbt.

[image]

Comment: *Trotz allen Suchens* hast Du diese Formulierung noch nicht gesehen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Genitiv-Form kommt vor allem in Formulierungen wie den folgenden vor:

> Trotz aller Versuche
>   Trotz allen/alles Geschreis

Die Form *trotz alles Geschreis* ist anscheinend (siehe http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zureden) korrekt, aber aus meiner Sicht mindestens ungebräuchlich.

Die Form, in der *trotz alles* alleine steht (ohne weitere Angabe trotz allen/alles *was*) ist mir jedoch noch nicht untergekommen und meiner Meinung nach auch nicht korrekt. Sprich, das folgende geht aus meiner Sicht nicht:

> Wir haben vieles probiert. Trotz alles hat es nicht geklappt.

PS: Je öfter ich in Gedanken *Trotz alles Geschreis...* vor mich hinsage, desto weniger schlimm klingt für mich auch diese Variante :-)

Answer (score 1):

Diese Form existiert sicher; allerdings wird sie wirklich selten verwendet. Ein Beispiel wäre:

> *Trotz alles* Aufwands, den wir in unsere Sache investiert haben, konnten wir keinen Gewinn erwirtschaften.

Häufigere Formulierungen wären beispielsweise

> Obwohl wir so viel Aufwand investiert haben,...
>
> Wir haben viel Aufwand investiert in unsere Sache, trotz allem...

Comment: Nein, es heißt *trotz allen Aufwands*.

Comment: Ich widerspreche. Nach kurzer Suche fand ich diesen Link http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zureden zum Wort Zureden auf der offiziellen Duden-Website. Siehe Beispiele.

Comment: Dann sage ich es anders: Ich habe noch nie jemand gehört/gelesen, der *trotz alles Aufwands* gesagt/geschrieben hätte. Und es klingt für mich nicht richtig. Aber ich nehme meinen Downvote zurück und ergänze meine Antwort entsprechend.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Bist Du so sicher ein so fotographisches Gedächtnis, für alles was Du gelesen hast, zu haben und eine so sichere Erinnerung für alles Gehörte?

Comment: @userunknown Ja.

Comment: Gewagte Behauptung, dürfte aber nichts zur Sache tun. Beweise und Quellen sind mMn letztlich entscheidend.

Comment: @Locké Naja, man kann sich jetzt an sowas aufhängen oder man kann den Satz einfach so verstehen, wie er gemeint war. Und es dürfte ja klar sein, wie er gemeint war. Jedenfalls bekommen solche Kommentare von mir eine entsprechende Antwort. Dumme Frage, dumme Antwort :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Du scheinst Dich noch wenig mit dem Phänomen der Selbsttäuschung beschäftigt zu haben. Wahrscheinlich bist Du aber eine außergewöhnliche Ausnahme.

Comment: Das selbe trifft wohl auf dich bezüglich Ausdrücken aus dem alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch zu. Es wird dich beruhigen zu hören, dass ich diesbezüglich nicht an Selbstüberschätzung leide, sondern lediglich eine allgemeine anerkannte Formulierung für "ich wüsste nicht, dass..." verwendet habe. Da anscheinend deine Hauptaufgabe hier jedoch zu sein scheint, den allgemeinen Ablauf mit sinnfreien Kommentaren zu stören (zumindest wenn es um Kommentare oder Antworten von mir geht), nehme ich es mit einem Lächeln.

Comment: Alles in allem scheint "*alle**n**" an dieser Stelle sehr häufig explizit für den Genitiv verwendet zu werden. Ich habe schon oft ähnliche Konstrukte wie diese hier gehört: "Das Gewicht alle**n** Mehls beträgt..." anstatt "Das Gewicht alle**s** Mehls beträgt...". Was von beidem richtig ist, weiß ich nicht.